# Perl array reference always rewrites over itself in a loop

Tags: arrays, perl, arrayref

I am trying to read some numbers from a text file and store it as a 2 dimensional array. I read a line and push into another array as an array reference. But I noticed that main array only has last line in all rows. How can i correct this? Thanks in advance. This is part i do it.

```
open IN, "a.txt";
@b=();

while (<IN>)

 { 
  $t =$_; 
  @a = split /\s+/,$t; 
  push(@b, \@a); 
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have only two arrays in total. You want one per line, plus `@b`. `my` creates a new variable each time it is executed, so you can use the following:

```
my @b;
while (<IN>) { 
    my @a = split;
    push @b, \@a; 
 }
```

By the way, you should always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Wauw is it only because i didn't use "my". Very interesting to be honest. I should learn to use it. And thanks

Comment: Because you didn't use `my`, your use of `@a` referred to the global `@a`, which is not recreated each time through the loop like you expected.  `my @a` creates a new `@a` each time.

Comment: @xcvbnm: You should `use strict` as ikegami says, and declare *all* your variables with `my`

Comment: But in this scenario - also ensure you do that inside the loop - `my @a` outside the loop will have the same result - you push a reference to the same array each time.